# Pandas plot series with series names in one row

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

I have a csv file like this

```
date, name, value
2016-09-01, alice, 10
2016-09-02, alice, 11
2016-09-01, bob, 8
2016-09-02, bob, 14
```

With pandas can I plot as a line chart? Or must I change the structure of the file to something similar to

```
date, alice, bob
2016-09-01, 10, 8
2016-09-02, 11, 14
```

Comment: go for pivoting your df, it is easier to plot and clearer to read the df along with the plot

Comment: @boud you have some example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pivot your dataframe to plot one curve per column:

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='name').plot()
```